# SQL Server (Using REPLACE and SUM) within the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 10 percentages, 5 have a completion of 50% our of 100% and the remaining 5 have 0% out of 100%

my aim is to get the 0%'s to be replaced by 100% and then calculate the 10 percentages together / 10

for example:

```
(Original Data)    ((0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0)/10)  = 0.35 (35%)   
(What I want)      ((0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1)/10)  = 0.75 (75%)
```

how is this achieved in SQL Server? I have tried `NULLIF` and `ISNULL` but i know these are incorrect, im not sure how to use the `REPLACE` statement within a SUM

PS... i dont want to actually replace the data within the table, its for the purpose of a view, thankyou, and also these are referenced within 10 different columns within 1 row

example:

```
select FinanceID, SUM(Percentage1 + Percentage2 + Percentage3 + Percentage4
+ Percentage5 + Percentage6 + Percentage7 + Percentage8 + Percentage9 
+ Percentage10 )/10 from FinanceTable
where FinanceID = 1
group by FinanceID
```

this query selects the 10 percentages and divides by the amount, now i need to replace the 0 values with 100, this could be any scenario where all have a value greater than 0 or a random percentage, for example Percentage 7 is the only one with a percentage above 0. and to clarify the 0% is stored in the table as 0%, not NULL

Comment: can you elaborate more clearly..

Comment: Can you post the actual query?

Comment: improve your sample data covering all scenarios

Comment: So "the 10 percentages" are 10 columns in the table?

Comment: yes, the 10 percentages are all columns within 1 row, and 1- gives the output 0.65 in this scenario, not 0.75

Comment: To pick a value based on a condition use `CASE..WHEN`. I'd rather UNPIVOT the table though, to convert the columns to tables, then do a single SUM

Comment: And by `0` you mean `0`, not `null` right?

Comment: yes, 0 is stored in the table NOT null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
create table #temp (financeId varchar(10),percentage1 decimal(6,2),percentage2 decimal(6,2),percentage3 decimal (6,2))
go
insert into #temp values ('ROW1',0.5,0,.75)
insert into #temp values ('ROW2',0.25,0.75,0)
insert into #temp values ('ROW3',0.4,0,.85)
go
select 
    sum(
    case isnull(percentage1,0) when 0 then 1 else percentage1 end +
    case isnull(percentage2,0) when 0 then 1 else percentage2 end +
    case isnull(percentage3,0) when 0 then 1 else percentage3 end 
    ) / 3
from #temp  
group by financeID
```

Comment: Didn't see that additional comment until after I submitted my response.

Answer (score 2):

Since all these values are in individual columns, `SUM` can not be used. `SUM` is used to sum values across rows, not across columns.

Instead you need to do something like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Percentage1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE Percentage1 END
  + CASE WHEN Percentage2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE Percentage2 END
  + CASE WHEN Percentage3 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE Percentage3 END
  + CASE WHEN Percentage4 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE Percentage4 END
  + ...
```

You could also transform your table into a long list of values, and then use `SUM`:

```
SELECT SUM(P) FROM (
    SELECT Percentage1 AS P ...
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Percentage2 ...
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Percentage3 ...
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

use this for all fields like i used for percentage1

```
(isnull(nullif(percentage1,0),1))
```

Comment: No reason to introduce NULLS when you can just check the values with CASE

Comment: i get the value 15.35 with my try

Comment: changed the '100' to '1' as u need to replaced to '1'

Answer (score 0):

You can convert each value with a `CASE` statement but it would be clearer to use `UNPIVOT` to convert percentage columns to rows like this:

```
SELECT financeId, SUM(CASE WHEN Pct = 0 THEN 1 ELSE Pct END)/10
FROM 
   (SELECT financeId, percentage1, percentage2, percentage3,...
   FROM #temp) p
UNPIVOT
   (Pct FOR Name IN (percentage1, percentage2, percentage3,...)
)AS unpvt
group by financeId;
```

This way you avoid duplicating the `CASE` statements for each field